# How to read RFID tag data in iOS App using NFC Reader hardware

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, nfc, rfid

There is small illustration of NFC Reader Hardware [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hLJOXAZulA&feature=relmfu)

Under this video as soon as user scan RFID tags it directly print tag numbers on notepad/safari.

My question is how we can read RFID tag data in iOS App using NFC Reader hardware.
Do we have to right down some programming like related API integration or it is possible through BluetoothManager class or programming is not at all required ?

How we have to capture that id string ?

I will be using [this device](http://serialio.com/products/RFID/Mobile/idChamp/idChampRS2ProxBT.php).

Thanks

Comment: It seems you have integrated NFC reader in iOS application, can you tell me steps of how did you achieve that, as iPhone by default does not have NFC reader. Thanks!

Comment: Hi,Tariq is there any sdk available for integrating RFID into my native ios-(objective-c) application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This RFID reader just emulates a BlueTooth keyboard, thus to the iOS device is just like someone types in the RFID code that has been scanned.

Comment: Okay I got your point. So as per my understanding if I have a textField then it will be automatically populated with RFID code as a  text. But what if I don't have any textfield in my controller ? Cause as per requirement I have to store ids in my array and in user interface I just have to show something like 1 Scanned... 3 scanned etc. There is no keyboard. Now where I will get those ids ?

Comment: Good question, you could add a hidden textfield and just handle all the input like you would normally. But if no bluetooth keyboard is connected the normal keyboard will be displayed.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. But what do you mean by bluetooth keyboard :-/
I knw only default keyboard which appear using UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

Comment: If the device is connected to a BlueTooth keyboard the default keyboard will not be shown. (meaning the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is not called). The textfield can now be filled using the bluetooth keyboard. Just grab a bluetooth keyboard and a iOS 4 device and pair the two, you will see what I mean.

Comment: Oh alrite... so in my case it will nt be connected to any bluetooth keyboard. I will get hardware in next week then I will test with hidden textField. I will update you my progress :) ... Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hi.. I am back :)... so i have just tested with NFC Reader.. its working pretty fine with hidden textView... but there is 1 problem i.e. basically if reader is connected to iphone then I have to write becomeFirstResponder in viewDidLoad to catch all tags and as it is connected to reader my keyboard is disable but as soon as i disconnect reader then keyboard is getting visible. Is there any way I can check who is responsible for keyboard ?

Comment: @Tariq : Did you write any special code to read the RFID data, moreover will it be work for any RFID reader? Please explain in little bit detail.